# Visual Studio: How to ABSOLUTE POSITION a web control?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, css-position, web-controls

I am a beginner. Just want to have 2 controls of any kind at absolute positions on a web page.
Example: a listbox at x = 0, y =0, and another listbox at x=300, y=0.

How do I do this absolute positioning using Visual Studio?

Thanks.

**I FOUND THE ANSWER** 
I can't answer my own question yet. So **don't bother answering this question**, when I am allowed to post my own answer I will do so.

Answer (score 0):

You use CSS and the `position: absolute`, `left` and `top` settings.

Comment: This answer is not terribly useful to a BEGINNER as I noted in the first sentence.

Comment: If you need to learn basic CSS and Html, I suggest you buy a book on the subject.  This site isn't the place to ask questions for easily answered topics.